# Live streaming with Flash AS3 to a non Flash Media Server?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rtmp, live-streaming, flash-media-server

I would like to create a video chat web app, similar to "Chat Roulette",
I'd like to use Flash for both receiving and streaming video & audio.

The main problem is that it seems like they always redirect you to purchase a Flash Media Server license and usage, instead of allowing you to host a server yourself.

Is there any good known alternative to that, that I can host by myself and that works well with the flash streaming APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Red5:
https://github.com/Red5/red5-server

It's an open source Java-based media server.

There are many other alternatives out there, but since I've only used FMS and Red5, I can't vouch for other solutions.

Some that might also be worth considering:

- Mammoth: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mammoth/
- MistServer: http://mistserver.org/products

Please keep support and community activity in mind when choosing a platform, it might come in useful to choose something that has an active community.

Comment: You know of a good alternative? Red5 just seems too bugged out.

Comment: I updated my original answer to include some other alternatives.
Red5 should work fine though, at least it used to work perfect in the past.